# How can we create the below UI as shown in Native Android

Tags: android, android-seekbar, android-vertical-seekbar

I have to implement the below seek bar as shown below.[image]

The left side round thumb icon can be dragged and can be placed to each corresponding numbers. The number's remain constant, only the thumb icon can be dragged to each position using finger. How can I make the thumb alone scroll ?

Comment: This looks like Fast Scroll not a `SeekBar` ..

Comment: @ADM- How can  i implement it? could you provide some sample for it?

Comment: @ADM- Any Update on this?

Comment: Your image does not quite makes it clear what exactly u want . If its fast Scroll then Just Search For `FastScrollRecyclerView` u will find bunch of libraries and examples . If not then u need edit your question with proper details  ..

Comment: @ADM-  I have updated the question as asked

Answer (score 2):

For the verical SeekBar, you can use the custom view that is [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AndroSelva/Vertical-SeekBar-Android/master/sample/src/android/widget/VerticalSeekBar.java) without much, if any, modification.

Update: Without modification except replace

```
int i=0;
i=getMax() - (int) (getMax() * event.getY() / getHeight());
```

with

```
int i = getMax() - (int) (getMax() * (event.getY() - getPaddingEnd()) / (getHeight() - getPaddingEnd()));
```

The *SeekBar* thumb can be defined as follows:

**seekbar_thumb.xml**

```
<shape 
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
    <size
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp" />
</shape>
```

Together these give us the following:

[image]

The goal now is to overlay what we have with the text. We can do this with a *ConstraintLayout* with nine *TextViews*. We will set the top and bottom *TextViews* and place the intervening *TextView* within a vertical chain. Embedded comments give more information about the layout.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!--    Since the SeekBar is rotated -90 degrees by the custom view, paddingEnd becomes
            the padding from the top of the rotated view.
    -->
    <com.example.verticalseekbar.VerticalSeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekbar"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="36dp"
        android:background="@drawable/seekbar_background"
        android:max="9"
        android:min="1"
        android:paddingEnd="48dp"
        android:progressDrawable="@null"
        android:thumb="@drawable/seekbar_thumb"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <!--    The SeekBar has an implicit left padding of 16dp, so the top margin for the top line
            of text is 48dp - 16dp == 36dp (SeekBar top padding less the left padding of this view.
            This value and the positioning of the top and bottom TextViews might be better under
            program control rather than specifying them here.
    -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:paddingStart="8dp"
        android:text="9     Incredible"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/seekbar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/seekbar"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread_inside" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingStart="8dp"
        android:text="8     Great"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView7"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/seekbar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView9" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingStart="8dp"
        android:text="7     Good"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView6"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/seekbar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView8" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingStart="8dp"
        android:text="6     Above Average"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/seekbar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView7" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingStart="8dp"
        android:text="5     Average (I'd drink it if it's free)"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/seekbar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView6" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingStart="8dp"
        android:text="4     Below Average"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/seekbar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView5" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingStart="8dp"
        android:text="3     Poor"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/seekbar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingStart="8dp"
        android:text="2     Terrible"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/seekbar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:paddingStart="8dp"
        android:text="1     Undrinkable"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/seekbar"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/seekbar" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: working fine. a bit if things needed to be added for animation also. worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Please check below code for vertical seeker in android

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;

public class VerticalSeekBar extends SeekBar {

    public VerticalSeekBar(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public VerticalSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public VerticalSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(h, w, oldh, oldw);
    }

   @Override
   public synchronized void setProgress(int progress)  // it is necessary for calling setProgress on click of a button
   {
    super.setProgress(progress);
    onSizeChanged(getWidth(), getHeight(), 0, 0); 
   }
    @Override
    protected synchronized void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(heightMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredHeight(), getMeasuredWidth());
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {
        c.rotate(-90);
        c.translate(-getHeight(), 0);

        super.onDraw(c);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (!isEnabled()) {
            return false;
        }

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                setProgress(getMax() - (int) (getMax() * event.getY() / getHeight()));
                onSizeChanged(getWidth(), getHeight(), 0, 0);
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

paste the code and save it. Now use it in your XML layout:

```
<android.widget.VerticalSeekBar
  android:id="@+id/seekBar"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="400dp"
  />
```

Comment: This is not the correct solution for my issue.